# When/where should openid tokens be validated in a pyramid application?

Tags: python, authentication, openid, pyramid

I am writing a small webapp using the pyramid framework. For authentication I use a service of the cloud infrastructure that supplies me with a javascript web token, which I can use to validate the identity of the user.

I am a bit unsure on how to incorporate this with pyramid, especially since most examples I found are either username-password based authentication frameworks, or they generate JWT tokens themselves (I just consume those by the identity provider).

Anyway, in the login view, I have currently a logic like this:

```
.....

user = validate_jwt_token_and_return_user(id_token, ** config)
if user:
    headers = remember(self.request, user.id)
    raise HTTPFound(location=next_url, headers=headers)
```

Now it seems that by this I store the user-ID as  a session cookie (?) and the user visits the next view, the user id is taken from the cookie?

Wouldn't it be better to store the jwt_token in the cookie and use this upon the next request to check whether the user's login attempt is valid?

Comment: Have a look at [`pyramid_jwt`](https://pypi.org/project/pyramid_jwt/) for usage and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can store the JWT token in a cookie. You choose the authentication policy - just write one that does that instead of using one that stores it in the session.